# Curl commands fails when data is send from file

Tags: json, curl, post

Hi I am sending the data through json file and sending that in curl command using the following command and I am getting following error

```
curl -k https://localhost:25678/api-name -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data @test.json
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

The contents of my file is like this

```
"{'secret': 'toMwVie86l8qlYG2dEiEmZQldZhiAYW6UDwXRkLLRR3qtoONwsSqhd5fPctTQzGSnlSpZPwb4MheUnLQ4z4wyrCd6jDQb3wqfqE3lDnrNpiQhfEU0qVKdBIDIbIck3WmhRqN9YXNEy/XSnsla6ZAUid5RkAZLOx8Lvg91NmgSog='}"
```

Could someone please help me if I am doing something wrong

Comment: could someone help me here please

Comment: Your _'test.json'_ is invalid. Remove the double quotes and convert the single quotes to double quotes: `{"secret": "[...]"}`.